# What does 白紙にかえって探さねばならぬ mean in this context

Tags: translation, meaning, jlpt, reading-comprehension

みなさんこんにちは。
I came across this paragraph in japanesetest4you site.

> 妻の掃除と整理の仕方、これはもう極端に偏執的である。たとえば自分の好きなところはピカピカ光るほど磨き上げるが、興味のないところは何年もほこりが積み放しになっている。家の中のある部分は精神質なくらい整然と物が並び、だれかが彼女の留守にほんの一ミリほど品物を動かしてもすぐに気づいてしまう。そのかわり、いつも手のつけようもないほどむちゃくちゃにものが突っ込んであるところが家の中に一、二ヶ所は必ずある。
>
> 妻のものの**しまい方**は普通の世間並みとは大分違う。普通の人なら大概たんすにしまう品が食器棚に入っていたり、流しの棚にあるはずのものが冷蔵庫にしまってあったりする。**探す以上一応我々の常識と因襲を全部脱ぎ棄てて、白紙にかえって探さねばならぬが**、そんなことは容易にできることではない。次に、彼女の物の置き方、並べ方はことごとく彼女の抱いている美の法則によって支配されているので、実用上の便宜というものは一切無視される。どんな不便を忍んでも彼女は自分の美を守り通そうとする。ときにわたしが抗議を申し込んでみてもとうていむだである。

The reading comprehension question is what does 白紙にかえって探さねばならぬ mean in this context? (The answer given is 常識的な考えは捨てて探すこと.)

Two of these phrases, both the question and the answer, are incomprehensible to me.

Also what is 捨てて探す? What is しまい方?

Can anyone explain what it means and translate the bold sentences in the paragraph?

Comment: 'sutetete sagasu' means something like 'throw away and search for'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

しまい方 is a colloquial of 片づけ方(かたづけかた)
Some people use 直し方(なおしかた) instead.

しまう
片づける
直す
is 
cleaning up the room by throw/store things into closet.

The wife is good at cleaning;
After her cleaning, there are no dirt. Ornaments are well displayed. Table surface are shiny.
Yet to accomplish such nifty space, she hides dishes, clothes, or any uninteresting things elsewhere.

Imagine that the husband wants to find his camera. A camera is supposed to be placed in a shelf,
but the wife might throw it into the cupboard(because she doesn't care where to hide ).

He says he must forget all the commonsense(白紙に返って) where the missing things are supposed to be put into before he begins searching.